# How to remove nail polish from nails?

Tags: personal-care

Many times we don't have nail polish remover around.
How to remove nail polish from nails of course with no nail polish remover around?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the coat is very old, you can just scratch your nail with your fingernail or a nail file to remove it. This might damage your nail.

Besides nail polish remover, there are various other personal-care products that you can use to remove nail polish.

However, the methods to use them slightly differ. I will add the *method-number* at the end of the product.

### What you can use:

- Spray Deodorant         *2*
- Top coat nail polish    *3*
- Nail polish you don't like    *3*
- Body spray         *1*
- Hair spray          *1*
- Perfume           *1*
- Hand sanitizer       *2*
- Ammonia           *1*
- Rubbing alcohol       *1*/*2*

### Methods

#### *1*: Add onto cotton and rub

1. Add a little of the product onto a cotton ball or the fluffy end of a q-tip (*Spray:* hold as close as possible to the nozzle to get the most of the product onto the cotton)
2. Rub the cotton ball or q-tip over your nail until the nail polish disappears

You may need to dampen the cotton with some warm water so that it doesn't stick to the nail.

#### *2*: Apply directly and rub

1. Squirt or spray the product directly onto your nail
2. Rub your nail with a handkerchief / napkin (spray) or with your fingertip (liquid)

#### *3*: MORE nail polish (no joke)

1. Apply the nail polish to your painted nail
2. Quickly get a cotton swab / ball and wipe the nail polish off
3. Repeat if necessary

Cotton may stick to your nail. If the nail polish is very old, it may not work as well.

**Caution:**

- Using sprays will affect the air-quality. Do this outside or at least in a room with a window open or in a bathroom with a fan.
- Whatever you do: **Wash your hands afterwards**. You're working with chemicals!

---

Source: [wikiHow - How to Remove Nail Polish Without Using Remover](http://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Nail-Polish-Without-Using-Remover)

Answer (score 1):

Soak fingertips in warm water for at least 15 mins+ then scrub nails with an abrasive, but not to abrasive, cloth to remove all traces of nail polish

Answer (score -1):

Also, nail polish remover is pretty similar to paint thinner which you might have around the house. Just be careful where you get it as it is not friendly to your body or lungs.